# Setting HTTPS as default in Tomcat 8

Tags: linux, https, tomcat8

Hosting a web portal in an AWS at https://portal.example.com using Tomcat 8 on a Linux EC2 instance

In order to access the portal, the address must be entered as https://.

I'd like users to be automatically sent to the proper address when they type in portal.example.com.

I've read a couple of instructions online and attempted to make adjustments, but can't seem to get anywhere.

I should probably also note that the service is running on 8443 and there are firewall rules in place to send traffic for 443 to 8443 within the Linux UFW.

Anyone have any good instructions or recommendations for completing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a non-SSL **Connnector** with a redirect to the SSL **Connector**:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    ....
    redirectPort="8443"/>
```

You will also need a forward setup for port 80 => 8080 to receive the HTTP traffic

Comment: Thanks! I had the connector but somehow overlooked the forwarding of 80 -> 8080. D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

I always went with Tomcat behind Apache Webserver. Could go with either mod-jk or simple proxy passing.